Query solr data in Admin UI
I tried to query my solr data via the Admin UI.

Error for the executed query.

I tried to query my solr data using SQL option on the Admin UI, but I'm unable to fetch any data.

Have you enabled the sql module as mentioned at https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/sql-query.html#module ?

@MatsLindh I did it by adding below lines on the solrconfig.xml file



but still its not resolved, please help to enable the module for sql

Where did you do this? Did you update the configuration in zookeeper? Did you use zkCli.sh? Did you verify that the library gets loaded when starting Solr in the logs? Did you follow the instructions in https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/solr-modules.html for enabling a module?

@MatsLindh I did it on the solrconfig.xml fie not in the zookeeper.
And, the library's are already there on the solr instance, we just mentioned the library path on the config to load the sql.jar files.

If you're running Solr in cloud mode (which it seems like from the interface you're showing), your configuration lives in Zookeeper - so it needs to be downloaded from there, changed, and then uploaded again - and the jar files either have to be stored in the local classpath on each node or uploaded to zookeeper as well - see the reference guide for library files.
